# Install ubuntu in MBR single boot

Tags: boot, mbr

Before marking my question as duplicate I'd  like to say that days ago when my problem showed up until now I've been searching for a solution to it but it seems a special situation (at least for me) which I can't handle so I came here as a last resort to solve my problem.

I had both ubuntu and windows 10 as dual boot install both as mbr and everything was going ok but once booted to windows 10 and something happened in the middle of operation which made that problem I believe. when searching for errors that appeared I found out that the hard drive may contained both GPT and mbr partitionings (somehow) and that lead to error. I had wiped my hard drive using ubuntu on a live CD using the command `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda` but that also didn't solve the problem.

**now**: I'm trying to install ubuntu as a single boot as mbr but I can't do it. it shows me those errors on live CD boot up on the background logs[image] [image]pardon my phone camera quality but it's the best I could get.

I don't even know whether it's either a software or a hardware problem with my drive but ubuntu continues and shows me this after instillation.
[image]

see ? the partitioning is `Unknown()`

Sorry for that long description. hope you can help me.

Comment: Hmm, the kernel is reporting an I/O error, that potentially means that your drive is failing.

Comment: so it's more likely to be a hardware error ?

Comment: Well, seeing as it has 5 bad sectors, there is a good chance that it is a hardware issue.

Comment: can you help identify it ? is it fixable ?

Comment: So I don't quite understand something - if the live DVD is failing to boot, then how did you get the screenshot of the partitioning? Did you mean to say that after you wiped it with `dd` you reinstalled and now the fresh install is failing to boot?

Comment: the live DVD doesn't fail to boot it actually boots but it shows those errors before it does so I thought those my have a relation with whats happening so I posted them .. actually when I select the option (delete all and install ubuntu) it continues well and thats what happened I took this screen shot after installing ubuntu but if I leave it after the first shutdown I can't boot to ubuntu again

Comment: *"if I leave it after the first shutdown I can't boot to ubuntu again"* that tells me that your hard drive is indeed failing.

Comment: can you tell me what is probably wrong with my hard drive so I can fix it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65837/discussion-between-meyer-and-android-dev).